# visual studio 2017 spa templates vue js missing

Tags: visual-studio, vuejs2, asp.net-core-2.0, typescript-typings, spa-template

I can see that lot of examples of Spa templates
        dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*

does have VueJs but when I install it I can't seem to see it on the list even with -l parameter.

does anyone know what is up with this ? or alternatively a full working SPA seed project? almost every project I tried, has some issues.

Thanks

Nero

Answer (score 3):

Are you getting an error message when running the install?

I was having the same issue, and it turned out to be an invalid NuGet package source. The installer fails to get the latest templates if it cannot access any of your package sources.

When I ran `PS C:\Users\me> dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*`

I would see an error in the terminal

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\wacht\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.4\scratch\restore.csproj...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\NuGet.targets(103,5): error : The local source '\\privateserver\NuGet' doesn't exist. [C:\Users\wacht\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.4\scratch\restore.csproj]
```

After I removed the inaccessible package source, the installed updated my local SPA templates and installed the Vue template.

Comment: nice find! this was exactly my issue... not good at the CL stuff & totally overlooked the errors!